# EA sending a mass of "SendMessage" commands despite prevention code in place

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

Morning Fellow Stackoverflowers

I'm currently testing out some code which is based around time of day with which an EA is allowed to trade. How would I prevent the EA from sending a bazillion emails - one will obviously do.

Only one was sent in another EA I have by applying `LastActiontime=Time[0];`, however, having applied the `LastActiontime=Time[0];`, its pinging a mass of messages....

What changes do I need to make to prevent this from happening?

See code below

```html
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                     EAServerVerificationPing.mq4 |
//|                        Copyright 2017, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2017, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict

datetime       LastActiontime;
int            timeOfDay;
int            hour;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//---
   RefreshRates();
//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//---
   
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
//---

   timeOfDay            =  DayOfWeek();
   hour                 =  Hour();
   
   if(timeOfDay == 1 && hour >= 2)
   if(LastActiontime!=Time[0])
   {
      //Code to execute once in the bar
      SendMail("Is your Trade Allowed? (FXVM)",
      "Yes, your trade is allowed"+
      "\n"+
      "\nPRIVACY NOTICE");
   }else{
      SendMail("Is your Trade Allowed? (FXVM)",
      "No, your trade is not allowed"+
      "\n"+
      "\nPRIVACY NOTICE");
   }  
   LastActiontime=Time[0]; <!------This should prevent a mass of messages from sending--->
}
  

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Much obliged :)

Comment: you have weird logic. 'if(LastActiontime!=Time[0])` then you send some kind of message, otherwise you send another message. altogether you send a message every tick. What you should do: `if(DayOfWeek()==MONDAY && Hour()>=2){if(Time[0]>LastActiontime){LastActiontime=Time[0];send();}}}` where `send()` is a function that sends a message (either on allowed or not - decide on that here or in a separate function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, The logic I am going for here is: as long as it's a Monday and either 2 am or later, it's OK to trade, otherwise it's not. The actual code this is based on has more logic however, in accordance with Stackoverflow convention, the "fat" has been removed so the community can only see the relevant code. Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain In the derrier however would you be able to alter my code with your answer? I've never come across that nested logic before? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  datetime       LastActiontime;
  int            timeOfDay;
  int            hour;
  
  int OnInit()
    {
  //---
     RefreshRates();   // <- useless
  //---
     return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
    }
  void OnDeinit(const int reason)
    {
  //---
     
    }
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  //| Expert tick function                                             |
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  void OnTick()
  {
  //---
  
     timeOfDay            =  DayOfWeek();
     hour                 =  Hour();
     
     if(DayOfWeek()==MONDAY && Hour()>=2)
     {
        if(Time[0]>LastActiontime)
        {
           LastActiontime=Time[0];send();
        }
     }
  }
  void send()
  {
     if(true) //put your logic here
     {
        SendMail("Is your Trade Allowed? (FXVM)",
              "Yes, your trade is allowed"+
              "\n"+
              "\nPRIVACY NOTICE");
     }
     else
     {
        SendMail("Is your Trade Allowed? (FXVM)",
           "No, your trade is not allowed"+
           "\n"+
           "\nPRIVACY NOTICE");
     }
  }
```